# Метод касательных

Tags: c, математика, численные-методы

Программа выдает -nan, в чем заключается ошибка ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double f(double x) {
    return (x * x - 2);
}
double f1(double x) {
    double h = 0.01;
    return ((f(x+h) - f(x-h))/2*h);
}
double f2(double x) {
    double h = 0.01, s;
    s = (f(x+h) - 2*f(x) + f(x-h))/h*h;
    return s;
}
double newton (double a, double b, double eps) {
    double xold, xnew, c;
    c = (a + b)/2;
        if(f1(c)*f2(c) > 0)
            xnew = a;
        else
            xnew = b;
        do {
            xold = xnew;
            xnew = xold - f(xold)/f1(xold);
        } while(fabs(xold - xnew) > eps);
        return xnew;
}
int main () {
    double a, b, eps;
    puts("eps a b");
    scanf ("%lf %lf %lf", &eps, &a, &b);
    printf ("%lf\n", newton(a, b, eps));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начните с изучения азов языка.

```
((f(x+h) - f(x-h))/2*h)
```

означает - поделить разность на 2 **И УМНОЖИТЬ** на `h`.

А это выражение

```
(f(x+h) - 2*f(x) + f(x-h))/h*h
```

по сути просто равно

```
(f(x+h) - 2*f(x) + f(x-h))
```

Из-за неверных производных (кстати, почему бы просто не взять `2*x`? :)) метод расходится...